# how to sed for certain parts of a string by delimiter

Tags: bash, sed

I have lots of different strings that look like `redhat-ubi-ubi7-7.8`

I want to use the string to make variables so that I end up having something like

```
vendor=redhat
product=ubi
image=ubi7
tag=7.8
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

With `bash` and a `here string`:

```
string='redhat-ubi-ubi7-7.8'
IFS=- read -r vendor product image tag <<< "$string"
echo "$vendor"
```

Output:

```
redhat
```

Comment: With GNU sed: `echo "$string" | sed -r 's/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/vendor=\1\nproduct=\2\nimage=\3\ntag=\4/'`

Answer (score 1):

Using P.E. parameter expansion.

```
string='redhat-ubi-ubi7-7.8'
vendor=${string%%-*}
tag=${string##*-}
image=${string%-*}
product=${image#*-}
product=${product%-*}
image=${image##*-}

printf '%s\n' vendor=$vendor product=$product image=$image tag=$tag
```

Output

```
vendor=redhat
product=ubi
image=ubi7
tag=7.8
```