# how to parse out string in to variables

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to be able read each line of a file that contains lines that look like: `redhat-ubi-ubi7-7.8` where `vendor=redhat, product=ubi, image_name=ubi7, tag=7.8` so that I can have these parsed in order to do something like:

```
  while read -r line; 
  do
    vendor=sed/awk
    product=sed/awk
    image_name=sed/awk
    version=sed/awk
    echo "Copying $image_name:$version into registry..."

    skopeo copy \
    docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/ironbank-images/"$line" \
    docker://"$REGISTRY_DOMAIN"/"$vendor"/"$product"/"$image_name":"$version" \
    --dest-creds="$REGISTRY_USERNAME":"$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" \
    --dest-tls-verify=false

  done < "$SYNC_IMAGES"
```

How can I separate this string out in order to get the desired result for my usecase?

Comment: Why are you doing this with a shell loop rather than doing the whole thing in `awk`?

Comment: What about [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60572406/3776858)?

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `read`'s multi-variable feature and bash's [`IFS`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS) would do the trick:

```
while IFS=- read -r vendor product image_name version; 
do
    echo "Copying $image_name:$version into registry..."

    skopeo copy \
        docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/ironbank-images/"${vendor}-${product}-${image_name}-${version}" \
        docker://"$REGISTRY_DOMAIN"/"$vendor"/"$product"/"$image_name":"$version" \
        --dest-creds="$REGISTRY_USERNAME":"$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" \
        --dest-tls-verify=false

done < "$SYNC_IMAGES"
```

Comment: That 2nd `echo` is good for debugging, but would prevent the code from running.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `awk` with `-` as the field separator.

```
awk -F- -v domain="$REGISTRY_DOMAIN" -v user="$REGISTRY_USER" -v pw="$REGISTRY_PASSWORD" '
    {   vendor = $1; product = $2; image_name = $3; version = $4;
        printf("echo \"Copying %s:%s into registry\"\n", image_name, version);
        printf("skopeo copy docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/ironbank-images/\"%s\" docker://\"%s\"/\"%s\"/\"%s\"/\"%s\":\"$version\" --dest-creds=\"%s\":\"%s\" --dest-tls-verify=false\n",
            domain, vendor, product, image_name, version, user, pw)
    }' < "$SYNC_IMAGES" | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to use P.E. parameter expansion.

```
while read -r string; do
  vendor=${string%%-*} version=${string##*-} image_name=${string%-*}
  product=${image_name#*-} product=${product%-*} image_name=${image_name##*-}

  echo "Copying $image_name:$version into registry..."

  echo skopeo copy \
        docker-archive:/opt/app-root/src/ironbank-images/"${vendor}-${product}-${image_name}-${version}" \
        docker://"${REGISTRY_DOMAIN}"/"$vendor"/"$product"/"$image_name":"$version" \
        --dest-creds="${REGISTRY_USERNAME}":"${REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" \
        --dest-tls-verify=false
done < "$SYNC_IMAGES"
```