# How to transfer variables in Bash

Tags: bash

I have little experience with Bash, but I read everything I found before writing here.

I have a text file with lines:

```
disk1
disk2
disk3
```

This file is the result of the command:

```
disk list | awk -F"|" '/backup/ {print $3}' | sed s/' '//g > backupdisks.txt
```

If we can get rid of it, and output the command and immediately convert the commands into variables, it will be even cooler.
The number of lines will change from time to time.

I need to take those lines in the Bash script and insert them in the

```
snapshot create --name ${disk}-$now --disk-name ${disk}
```

I don't understand how to import each line into the variable disk1, disk2, etc., and to then substitute them into the second command as well.

I read and tried

```
while read -r disk
do
    echo "${disk}"
done < backupdisks.txt
```

And also:

```
read var2 var3 <data-file

echo "var2 = $var2 var3 = $var3"
```

and also

```
file=text.txt
while IFS= read -r line
do
        # echo line is stored in $line
    echo $line
done < "$file"
```

I guess there isn't any way I can figure out how this works.

Коллеги божественно. Благодаря вашим ответам я начинаю понимать, как это работает. Я вставлю сюда весь скрипт, потому что он может пригодиться всем, кто работает в Яндекс Облаке (резервной копии нет((( )

Пытаюсь сделать трехдневные бэкапы всех дисков, которые начинаются с бэкапа Вот что у меня получилось и работает:

```
#!/bin/bash
getDate() {
    date '+%d%m%Y'
}
getDate1() {
    date '+%d%m%Y' --date='3 days ago'
}
now=$(getDate)
del=$(getDate1)

for disk in `yc compute disk list --folder-id "id вашей папки" | awk -F"|" '/backup/ {print $3}' | sed s/' '//g`
do
    (
        yc compute snapshot create --folder-id "id вашей папки" --name ${disk}-$now --disk-name ${disk} &&\
        yc compute snapshot delete --folder-id "id вашей папки" --name ${disk}-$del
    ) & disown
done
```

Comment: Does `while read -r disk; do snapshot create --name "${disk}-$now" --disk-name "$disk"; done < backupdisks.txt` do what you want?  If not, why not?

Comment: If you can ensure from the problem domain, that each line produced from your pipe is a single word (i.e. no white space inside the "disk names"), the simplest way to put it into an array variable would be `disk_array=( $(disk list | .....) )`

Comment: Please translate the Russian parts.

Answer (score 0):

The original question is how to transfer variables.

My answer doesn't actually address the OP's question, but it provides an alternative approach to what they are trying to do.  I will also give the answer to the original question below the *"Alternative approach"*.

#### Alternative approach to the problem

```
disk list | awk -F"|" '/backup/ { print "now=$(date \047+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S\047) snapshot create --name " $3 "-$now --disk-name " $3 }'
```

This way you will get the output:

```
now=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') snapshot create --name disk1-$now --disk-name disk1
now=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') snapshot create --name disk2-$now --disk-name disk2
now=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') snapshot create --name disk3-$now --disk-name disk3
```

This can in turn be piped to Bash to actually run it.

So in the end:

```
disk list | awk -F"|" '/backup/ {print "now=$(date \047+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S\047) snapshot create --name " $3 "-$now --disk-name " $3 }'  | bash
```

#### Important note

There is very little error checking in my code. For production code, it's always a good idea to test this type of stuff out very well. For example, we are assuming that the `disk list` command outputs the correct list correctly every time, etc.

#### ***Note*** about $now

If you want to keep identical timestamp for all disks, then you can put it as an echo in the *BEGIN* block in [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
disk list | awk -F"|" 'BEGIN { print "export now=\047$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)\047 " } /backup/ {print "snapshot create --name " $3 "-$now --disk-name " $3 }'
```

This results in the output:

```
export now='$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)';
snapshot create --name disk1-$now --disk-name disk1
snapshot create --name disk2-$now --disk-name disk2
snapshot create --name disk3-$now --disk-name disk3
```

You can adjust the value of date or however you get "now" the way you like.

I hope that this gives you starting point.

#### Transferring variables

Let's say that my alternative approach is not valid for the general question of `transferring variables`. Then we can approach it like this:

So let's say we have a list that we want to assign to a variable in Bash one at a time, but we want to preserve and then use that result elsewhere:

```
cat file | while read line ; do
     do_something_with $line
done
```

But we can go further:

```
cat file | while read line ; do
     construct_another_command_with $line
done | command_processor
```

An example would be to create lines of a shell script like I did in the "*Alternative approach*" to create a set of lines that Bash would understand as a script and then pipe those lines to Bash to execute them.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one variable per line, [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) is great:

```
disk list \
    | awk -F"|" '/backup/ {print $3}' \
    | sed s/' '//g \
    | xargs -I '{}' snapshot create --name {}-$now --disk-name {}
```

`-I '{}'` tells `xargs` to replace the string `{}` with the line it reads from the file. Note that `$now` is not replaced by xargs and is replaced by regular shell substitution.

For a more generic answer, where lines can contain multiple arguments arguments, then you can use a `while`+`read` parsing (a real example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60573706/10678955)):

```
disk list \
    | awk -F"|" '/backup/ {print $3}' \
    | sed s/' '//g \
    | awk '{ print systime() " " $0 }' \
    | while read now disk; do \
        snapshot create --name "${disk}-${now}" --disk-name "${disk}"
    done
```

That `awk '{ print systime() " " $0 }'` prepends the current timestamp (to be used as `${now}`) to your normal lines (to be used as `${disk}`).

So every line would look like this:

```
1653864092 /backup/disk1
1653864092 /backup/disk2
1653864092 /backup/disk3
```

Namely, two variables per line.

Then, we use `read` to read the two variables and just use them in a command like in a regular shell, very similar to [Ahmed Masud's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72426299/how-to-transfer-variables-in-bash/72426443#72426443) "Transferring variables" answer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but I think you can use a subshell for this, like so:

```
for disk in $(disk list | awk -F"|" '/backup/ {print $3}' | sed s/' '//g); do snapshot create --name ${disk}-$now --disk-name ${disk}; done
```

Don't forget to define `$now` before running this loop.